Does every recursively axiomatizable first-order theory over a finite language have a finitely axiomatizable definable extension?
I was inspired to ask this question because of a previous question some other user asked, here: Does "every" first-order theory have a finitely axiomatizable conservative extension?. In that question, the user asked if every recursively axiomatizable first-order theory over a finite language has a conservative extension which is finitely axiomatizable. The answer was affirmative. I am now asking the same thing, but with "definable extension" in place of conservative extension. I know that while every definable extension is conservative, not every conservative extension is a definable extension.

I may be misunderstanding something, but if it’s a definable extension, can’t you just use the definitions to translate back to the original language and obtain that the original theory must be finitely axiomatizable?
